# How to solve this warning: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: codeigniter-3

Recently, I had a problem as:

```
Warning:include(C:\xampp\htdocs\crackverbal\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\crackverbal\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\crackverbal\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\crackverbal\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269

Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\crackverbal\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\crackverbal\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\crackverbal\application\views\errors\html\error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\crackverbal\system\core\Exceptions.php on line 269
```

I used `Xampp` and `codeigniter-3`.

Answer (score 13):

I am guessing that
Under `application\view\errors\html\` Folder, `error_php.php` file does not exist **Or**
Under `application\view\` Folder, `errors` folder does not exist at all.

You can create dummy file and see if there is any error.

Under `application/view/`, create folder name `errors`, 

then in `errors` folder, create folder name `html`

then in `html` folder, create php file name `error_php.php`

In `error_php.php`,

```
<?php echo "Sample text."; ?>
```

Comment: That worked pretty good.

Answer (score 3):

Just copy error folders in your codeigniter application to codeigniter view folder.
It will correct error page path. And the warnings will removed.

Answer (score 3):

copy `"errors"` folder from `"codeigniter3/application/views"` and paste it into your project `("my_project/application/views")`.

---

Paste the below code into `index.php`

```
$view_folder = '';

// The path to the "views" folder

    if ( ! is_dir($view_folder))
    {
        if ( ! empty($view_folder) && is_dir(APPPATH.$view_folder.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
        {
            $view_folder = APPPATH.$view_folder;
        }
        elseif ( ! is_dir(APPPATH.'views'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR))
        {
            header('HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable.', TRUE, 503);
            echo 'Your view folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: '.SELF;
            exit(3); // EXIT_CONFIG
        }
        else
        {
            $view_folder = APPPATH.'views';
        }
    }

    if (($_temp = realpath($view_folder)) !== FALSE)
    {
        $view_folder = $_temp.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    else
    {
        $view_folder = rtrim($view_folder, '/\\').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }

    define('VIEWPATH', $view_folder);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should download a fresh codeigniter folder and copy the error folder in the views folder.
Paste it in your own views folder.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create application / view / folder,
2. in errors folder, create html folder
3. create php filename error_php.php in the html folder

Answer (score 0):

please check your folder name may have a space like like: localhost/code igniter/welcome

Answer (score 0):

I just copied "errors" folder from "codeigniter3/application/views" in newly unzipped codeigniter3 folder and paste it into my project ("my_project/application/views"). It solved the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

> copy errors folder from another codeignator views folder and paste it inside views
> This is simple way to remove all errors.
> Don't create custom errors folder it gives you so many errors

Comment: why is this blockquoted? what/who are you quoting?

Answer (score 0):

As it's said in the [CI Forum](https://forum.codeigniter.com/showthread.php?tid=1510)

> In CI2, error message templates are in application/errors, whereas in CI3 they are in application/views/errors/html.
> Move your error messages into the (new) correct folder, and that should solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

Check the routs.php file in application>config/routs.php file and change `$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome'`

to

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'your default controller name';
```